# How To Skip To A Part Of Page In Horizontal Scrolling Website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am making a horizontal scrolling website made out of many divs under the className "slide". I want to include buttons in the navbar that skip to individual slides. How would I go about this?

This is the code I use for my horizontal scrolling website, it scrolls with the mouse scroll:

```
//homePage.js
<div className='home'>
  <div className='slidesWrapper'>
    <div className='slide one'></div>
    <div className='slide two'></div>
    <div className='slide three'></div>
    <div className='slide four'></div>
  </div>
</div>

//homePage.css
.home {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;

  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: calc(sum of all slide widths);

  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  //slides are of varying width declared by the second classNames (one, two, three, etc.)

  display: flex;
}

.one {
 width: 100vw;
}

.two {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, no-frills way to do this is to use a simple anchor element to link to an element on the same page.

From the "Linking to an element on the same page" example on the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Examples):

```html
<!-- <a> element links to the section below -->
<p><a href="#Section_further_down">
  Jump to the heading below
</a></p>

<!-- Heading to link to -->
<h2 id="Section_further_down">Section further down</h2>
```

Comment: is it possible to do this with an animation? Like instead of jumping there it scrolls to there?

Comment: @ZKJ keep in mind that neither Safari nor IE11 support the `scroll-behavior: smooth` CSS, and IE11 doesn't support the JS `behavior: smooth` option.


https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_scrolltooptions_behavior

Comment: istg its always safari making life harder, thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to scroll to a certain target. Here's an example

```
$(function(){

   var trigger = $('.trigger'); // your trigger for click event
   var section = $('.div'); // your class goes here to scroll to

   trigger.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(section).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```